# Is there a way to drag and copy, but prevent the drop with "draggable"? (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, html, drag-and-drop, draggable

Right now I have a functional drag and copy. I was wondering if there was any way to drag copy, but not drop. For example, if a user held the shift key, he/she could rapidly click and drop clones without dropping the dragged element. If search high and low through the documentation and haven't found anything.

Here is my code https://jsfiddle.net/jado66/f8b4ms36/2/ :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Drag Copy</title>
</head>
<style>

* {user-select: none; } 
.cell {width:50px;height:50px;
  }
img {width:50px;height:50px;cursor: move;}
table td #dropTable td:hover{background: #dedede;}
#dropTable {
    border-spacing: 5px;
    border: 1px solid #dedede;
}
.droppable:hover{
    transform: scale(1.05);
    transition-duration: 0.3s;
}

#dropTable tbody { height:300px; overflow-y:auto;  }

</style>

<body>
   

     <!-- Drag Table -->
    
        <table style="border-spacing: 5px;">
            <tr>
                <td id="image1">
                    <div class = "cell" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
                        <img class = "droppable newGate" src="droppable" src="https://picsum.photos/500/500?random=1"   
                      ondragstart="dragStart(event)" id="1" draggable="true"/> </div>
                </td>
                <td id="image2">
                    <div class = "cell " ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
                        <img class = "droppable" src="https://picsum.photos/500/500?random=2"   
                      ondragstart="dragStart(event)" id="2" draggable="true" /> </div>
                </td>
    
            </tr>
        </table>
        <hr>
        <!-- Drop Table -->
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <table id="dropTable" >
                    <tr >
                        <td> <div class = "cell"></div></td> 
                        <td> <div class = "cell" ></div></td>
                        <td> <div class = "cell" ></div></td>
                        <td> <div class = "cell" ></div></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td> <div class = "cell" ></div></td>
                        <td> <div class = "cell" ></div></td>
                        <td> <div class = "cell" ></div></td>
                        <td> <div class = "cell" ></div></td>
                    </tr>
                    </tr>
                        <td> <div class = "cell" ></div></td>
                        <td> <div class = "cell" ></div></td>
                        <td> <div class = "cell" ></div></td>
                        <td> <div class = "cell" ></div></td>
                    </tr>
                    </table>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    <script>
    
const cells = document.querySelectorAll(".cell:empty"); //We only want to add event listeners to empty cells
for (const cell of cells){
    cell.addEventListener('dragover',allowDrop);
    cell.addEventListener('drop',drop);
}

function dragStart(evt)
{
    evt.dataTransfer.setData("Text",evt.target.id);
}

function drop(evt)
{
    var data = evt.dataTransfer.getData("Text");
    var nodeCopy = document.getElementById(data).cloneNode(true);
    nodeCopy.id = Date.now(); /* We cannot use the same ID */
    evt.target.appendChild(nodeCopy);
    
    if (evt.shiftKey){
        console.log("Shift key pressed. Copy but keep drag");
      //Invoke drag command, or prevent drop, etc.
    }
}

function allowDrop(ob)
{
    ob.preventDefault();
}
    
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Your drag and copy is working. So what is the question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### In short, no

To answer your question if it's possible to prevent the drop event when the user releases the mouse button: no.

From [the spec](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dnd.html#drag-and-drop-processing-model):

> Otherwise, if the user ended the drag-and-drop operation (e.g. by releasing the mouse button in a mouse-driven drag-and-drop interface), or if the drag event was canceled, then this will be the last iteration.

It might however be possible to instantly fire a new DragStart event as the user drops the node, but I couldn't get this to work. Couldn't find anything in the spec that said anything about that not being possible but I could be wrong.

### A workaround for your particular use case

This is just a proof of concept fiddle, code doesn't look great and I'm sure it has bugs, but it does what you ask: https://jsfiddle.net/y9Lpxdea/3/. Hold your shift key and drag over the slots to clone the current object being held.

By storing the id of the element you want to clone from `onDragStart` in a variable (*not in the DataTransfer object as [DataTransfer.getData() is only accessible on the `drop` event](https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110113/dnd.html#drag-data-store-mode)*) you can access the ID of the currently held object in the `onDragEnter` event and then duplicate the child from there. I left the current drag & drop functionality without holding the shift key intact.

```js
let dragId = null;

function dragStart(evt)
{
    evt.dataTransfer.setData("Text",evt.target.id);
    dragId = evt.target.id;
}

function dragEnter(evt)
{
    if (evt.shiftKey && dragId){
        var nodeCopy = document.getElementById(dragId).cloneNode(true);
        nodeCopy.id = Date.now(); /* We cannot use the same ID */
        evt.target.innerHTML = "";
        evt.target.appendChild(nodeCopy);
    }
}

function drop(evt)
{
    var data = evt.dataTransfer.getData("Text");
    var nodeCopy = document.getElementById(data).cloneNode(true);
    nodeCopy.id = Date.now(); /* We cannot use the same ID */
    evt.target.appendChild(nodeCopy);
    dragId = null;
}
```